# APK that needs another apk to function

Tags: android

I am implementing a kind of location provider that I would like to distribute as an apk. If someone implements an application that uses the classes of my apk it is necessary that my apk is installed on the device first. My "location provider" offers an API that can be used by other programmers (it has no UI).

I wonder if it is even possible to do something like this. Normally I would use a jar but it is easier to distribute as a apk.

Is it possible to include an apk in for example Eclipse so that other programmers can use my API for their applications? I tried it but did not get it to work but I am also not an expert in Eclipse.

Hope someone has done something like that already and can give me a hint.

Thanks,
Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to include an apk in for example Eclipse so that other programmers can use my API for their applications?

No. Use a JAR or an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best way to do this is with [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

So basically, you would set up a URI, something like content://com.yoursite/locations, and your app would return a list of locations, or whatever it promised to return.

One example on how to do this would be the [Notepad Code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) that comes with the SDK.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but this seems not to be a solution to my problem.

Comment: I have a apk file and I want to use it in another Android application in Eclipse. I can import it and it will be included under "Referenced Libraries" but the classes in the apk are not accessible (NoClassDefFoundError). Anyway thank you for your reply.

Comment: MMm...okay, so you want the developer to bundle your APK and his/hers/its APK, to make one large APK, yes?  That seems problematic, rather than having the users download both APKs.  Using APKs seems a bit problematic, and AFAIK, the best way to do this would be to just release a jar file.  But I've never tried to embed one APk in another, so I guess there may be some way to do it properly.

Comment: Yes, kind of. I want others to be able to reference my apk in their projects so that they can make use of my API. It seems possible since I can import my apk in another project. I just recognized that the exported apk does not include my classes anymore and I guess this is the problem. I need to find out why the apk does not contain my classes anymore. Thanks for your time

Comment: Android doesn't use JVM classes.  Rather, it turns JVM code into DalvikVM code, and the extension for that is .dex, so all of your executable code is in the classes.dex file, unless of you course you used the ndk.

Comment: Okay, now I learned a bit more. Thanks. Well, than I do not see a possibility to import an apk into Eclipse and make its content accessible to other applications. I think I will use a jar :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import ANYTHING into eclipse, but that doesn't mean it's going to have classes available to you.

If you're trying to call someone else's application, and you have an intent you can target (like if you wanted to scan a barcode using the ZXing app), you can call that intent, and if it fails, redirect the user to the market to download it (then next time you call it, it'll succeed).

If you're trying to wrap someone else's apk, that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the redirect. This is possible. But right now I just want to make my own apk file accessible to another Android project that I write for testing. To make it clearer: I have written a program (program1) that uses an online database to resolve a given lat/lon (this comes from some application which uses the API of program1) position into a cellid. My program than observes that cellid and gives an notification if the current cellid contains the lat/lon. To test this I am writing an application that needs the API from program1.

Comment: To use the API from program1 I need to access the functions in program1 but I do not get it to work. Maybe it is just not possible like that or I just cannot see how.

Comment: As Leif said, I think Content Providers is the right way to go here.